# Elm `update` is not executing the case statement when dropdown's value is changed

Tags: elm

I am new to Elm. I am not able to call the update function once the dropdown value changes.

Scenario:
I have two dropdowns `Grade` and `Environment`. What I want is when `Grade` dropdown values change, the options of `Environment` dropdown will dependently change.

For example, if `Grade` dropdown value is `3` then the options of `Environment` should change to `Imagine Math`

```
    gradeDropdown : String -> List String -> Html Msg
    gradeDropdown grade grades =
        let
            buildOption =
                gradeOption grade
        in
            select [ class "importWizard--gradeSelection", name "gradeSelection", onChange (UpdateStudent Grade) ]
                (map buildOption grades)

    gradeOption : String -> String -> Html Msg
    gradeOption optSelectedVal temp =
        let
            optSelected =
                temp == optSelectedVal
        in
            option [ value temp, selected optSelected ] [ text temp ]

    environmentDropdown : Model -> String -> List String -> String -> Html Msg
    environmentDropdown model learningEnvironment learningEnvironments selectedGrade =
        let
            buildOption =
                environmentOption model learningEnvironment
            blueprint_grades = ["PreKindergarten", "Kindergarten", "1"]
            environmentDropdownOption =
              if (selectedGrade == "" || (List.member selectedGrade blueprint_grades)) then
                ["Blueprint"]
              else if (selectedGrade == "2") then
                learningEnvironments
              else
                ["Imagine Math"]
        in
            select [
              class "importWizard--learningEnvironmentSelection"
              , name "learningEnvironmentSelection"
              , onChange (UpdateStudent LearningEnvironments)
            ]
            (map buildOption environmentDropdownOption)

    environmentOption : Model -> String -> String -> Html Msg
    environmentOption model optSelectedVal temp =
        let
            optSelected =
                temp == optSelectedVal
        in
            option [ value temp, selected optSelected ] [ text temp ]
```

And in **Update**

```
update : Flags -> Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
    update flags message model =
        case message of
            UpdateStudent updateType newValue ->
                let
                    validate =
                        validateStudent flags validatableFieldsForScreen
                in
                    case updateType of
                        LastName ->
                            ( validate { model | lastName = newValue } <| Just LastNameField, Cmd.none )

                        FirstName ->
                            ( validate { model | firstName = newValue } <| Just FirstNameField, Cmd.none )

                        Sin ->
                            ( validate { model | sin = newValue } <| Just SinField, Cmd.none )

                        Grade ->
                            ( validate { model | grade = newValue, selectedGrade = newValue } Nothing, Cmd.none )

                        LearningEnvironments ->
                            ( validate { model | learningEnvironments = newValue } Nothing, Cmd.none )
```

**View:**

```
, td [ class wizardTableInput ] [ gradeDropdown model.grade flags.grades ]
, td [ class wizardTableInput ] [ environmentDropdown model model.learningEnvironments flags.learningEnvironments model.selectedGrade ]
```

In this code, the environment dropdown's value is changing, however the model's value is not updated. From what I understand, I can see is environment dropdown's id re-rendered, but it is not updating the model's value of `learningEnvironments`. This means it is not executing the `update` function matching `LearningEnvironments`.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a known-bug or just a known-difficiency. But you'll need to https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/html/latest/Html-Keyed to ensure that the second dropdown is redrawn when you need it to be

Comment: @SimonH but how should I implement on this scenario

Comment: I used `onInput` instead of `onChange` for select event. Maybe you can give it a try.

Comment: I tried with the `onChange` event also, but it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

`select` widgets where the options change is one of the use cases for `Html.Keyed.node`

Use a helper function like the one bellow:

```
keyedSelect : (String -> a) -> String -> List ( String, String ) -> Html a
keyedSelect message selectedValue kvs =
    let
        toOption ( k, v ) =
            ( k
            , option
                [ value k
                , selected (k == selectedValue)
                , disabled (k == "-1")
                ]
                [ text v ]
            )
    in
    Keyed.node "select"
        [ class "form-control", onChange message ]
        (List.map toOption kvs)
```

I usually have a `"Please select Foo"` first option with the value `-1` if the user never selected any of the options. This is why the code checks for `-1` and disables the option. You can remove the `disabled` attribute if you don't need it.

Comment: thanks, @pdamoc for the answer, but I tried with the same solution but it didn't work. Yeah thought for the same to put the option for `select` but I need to set the default value.

Comment: Consider creating an Ellie with the problem that you are experiencing. 
https://ellie-app.com/new and describe what you see happening and what you would have expected to happen. 

I might have misunderstood you problem entirely.

Comment: so consider in you ellie file, when I click on `+1` button and increase the value of that particular value and when I click on the `-1` button in decrease the value. but what I am facing is, so for example when I click on `+1` button it will display the incremented value but it actually not increase the model value, and when I will decrease by clicking the `-1` but it actually decreases the value by initial

Comment: In this use case it looks like you are actually altering a value that composes with another value to give what you want display. It's like instead of altering the `counter` you keep the counter the same and you alter a `deltaCounter` that you later display with something like `text <| String.fromInt (model.counter + model.deltaCounter)`. At least this is what I understand from what you are describing.